# Variable from external Batch file not working within main Batch file

Tags: batch-file, classpath

Right now I'm using two Batch files, well call them variables.cmd and main.cmd for this example. The variable.cmd file is to be used for externalizing a set of variables that might be used with multiple other batch files.

Now every variable has no problem being accessed in the main.cmd file except CLASSPATH. When echo is called within variables.cmd the CLASSPATH is correctly created, but when echoed in the main.cmd file I get the following result:

```
!CLASSPATH!;C:\ipp\deploy\lib\app\momex-webservice-client.jar;C:\ipp\deploy\resources
```

Any ideas on whats happening and how it can be resolved?

This is the main.cmd file:

```
@echo off

call variables.cmd

echo %JAVA_HOME%
echo %DEPLOY%
echo %DEBUG%
echo %DEBUG_PORT%
echo %JAVA_OPTIONS%
echo %CLASSPATH%
```

This is the variables.cmd file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30"
set DEPLOY=C:\ipp\deploy
set DEBUG=false
set DEBUG_PORT=15000

set JAVA_OPTIONS="
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs=%DEPLOY%\lib\endorsed
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump="true" 
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dconfiguration.properties=%DEPLOY%\resources\vendor.configuration.properties 
if "%DEBUG%"=="true" (
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=15000,suspend=n,server=y
)

set CLASSPATH=%DEPLOY%
for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\lib\system\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\lib\app\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\tools\jaxws-ri\lib\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DEPLOY%\resources
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--main.bat--
 @echo in main.bat
 @set CLASSPATH="This is a failed test"
 @echo The current classpath is %CLASSPATH%
 @echo going to call variables.bat
 @call variables.bat
 @call temporary.bat
 @echo back in main.bat
 @echo The current classpath is %CLASSPATH%
 @echo main.bat -- all done

 --variables.bat--
 @setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 @echo In variables.bat
 @set something="This is a successfull test"
 @echo set classpath=!something! > temporary.bat
 @endlocal
 @echo variables.bat is finished
```

Comment: I just gave it a try too. Works great! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified variabled.cmd file:

```
@echo off

set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30"
set DEPLOY=C:\ipp\deploy
set DEBUG=false
set DEBUG_PORT=15000

set JAVA_OPTIONS="
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs=%DEPLOY%\lib\endorsed
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump="true" 
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dconfiguration.properties=%DEPLOY%\resources\vendor.configuration.properties 
if "%DEBUG%"=="true" (
    set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=15000,suspend=n,server=y
)

set CLASSPATH=%DEPLOY%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\lib\system\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\lib\app\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

for %%i in (%DEPLOY%\tools\jaxws-ri\lib\*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%i
)

endlocal & set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%DEPLOY%\resources
```

The only changes are the position of `setlocal` command and an `endlocal` in the *same line* of the last set of CLASSPATH variable. This way, the values set in this Batch file remains for main.bat file and Delayed Expansion is enabled when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The setlocal at the top of your variables.cmd specifically causes variables defined within it to be "local" -- and therefore not "in scope" to main.cmd

Comment: Thanks for this. That makes sense, but how do I manage to use the for loops with the !CLASSPATH! without using setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion? Calling an endLocal will cause the CLASSPATH to revert to what it was before setLocal was used.

Comment: Yes, a catch-22 to be sure -- only thing I can think of is to have your "variables.cmd" file write out a temporary ".cmd" or ".bat" file that contains the fully exanded classpath setting -- then change you "main.cmd" to call "variables.cmd" first and the "temporary.cmd" second -- the temporary file you construct will not contain the "setLocal" and changes it makes to the environment should be visible to "main" -- good luck!

Comment: One other thing worth trying is to use "endlocal" in your variables.cmd file -- in theory changes to the environment made after the endlocal statement should be reflected back to "main"

Comment: I'll give your first idea a go. As for the second one, (i think) calling endLocal in the variables.cmd file will either prevent the needed EnableDelayedExpansion or prevent the CLASSPATH changes that occurred during the for loops from being passed into main.

Comment: Yes - it does I tried a simple prototype of the first idea and it worked -- I've posted it for you